# Python - how to sort and replace values in an array based on a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, for-loop, append

I have created an array that pulled data from different files and inserted it into the array.  This data is of varying # of values 1-7 and order.
i.e. one file can have 3 rows of

```
label1
label4
label3
```

the next file may only have

```
label3
```

and another yet may have

```
label7
label1
label3
label2
```

I have created a Dictionary

```
Dict = {1:'label1',
        2:'label2',
        3:'label3',
        4:'label4',
        5:'label5',
        6:'label6',
        7:'label7'}
```

I want to

1. loop through the array
2. set each label to the dictionary value (i.e. if label4 then it =4)
3. order it in the order 1-7
4. for the missing values, put a 0 in that spot
5. for the spots with values, put a 1 in that spot

i.e. for `[label1,label4,label3]`

1. replace with dictionary value and sort --  `[1,3,4]`
2. loop through array, and if that number is missing, put a 0 in that spot, everything else turn to 1 in same location it was in --  `[1,0,1,1,0,0,0]`

Essentially, I am one-hot-encoding it.

This is what I am trying, but I am messing up the loop logic somewhere:

```
y_temp = []
for j in y:
    for k in y[j]:
        if y[j,k]== Dict[1]:
            y_temp[k] = y_temp[k].append('1')
            else:
                y[k] = y_temp[k].append('0')
        elif y[j,k] == Dict[2]:
            y_temp[k] = y_temp[k].append('2')
            else:
                y[k] = y_temp[k].append('0')
        elif y[j,k] == Dict[3]:
            y_temp[k] = y_temp[k].append('3')
            else:
                y[k] = y_temp[k].append('0')
        elif y[j,k] == Dict[4]:
            y_temp[k] = y_temp[k].append('4')
            else:
                y[k] = y_temp[k].append('0')
        elif y[j,k] == Dict[5]:
            y_temp[k] = y_temp[k].append('5')
            else:
                y[k] = y_temp[k].append('0')
        elif y[j,k] == Dict[6]:
            y_temp[k] = y_temp[k].append('6')
            else:
                y[k] = y_temp[k].append('0')
        elif y[j,k] == Dict[7]:
            y_temp[k] = y_temp[k].append('7')
            else:
                y[k] = y_temp[k].append('0')
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback you are getting when you run your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a little bit not quite right in each version of the solution.  I ended creating a solution that combined some components of both.  Thank you both @Alain T and @Phineas for your wonderful solutions and answers to my questions.  I couldn't have done it without either of you.  Thanks!!

```
Dict = {'label1': 0,
        'label2': 1,
        'label3': 2,
        'label4': 3,
        'label5': 4,
        'label6': 5,
        'label7': 6}

labels_arr = [['label1', 'label5', 'label4'], ['label1', 'label4', 'label3'], 
             ['label1', 'label3'], ['label1'], ['label1', 'label4', 'label3'], 
             ['label1', 'label3', 'label4'], 
             ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4', 'label5', 'label6', 'label7']]

nums_arr  =[]                      # this array saves the list after each loop
for i in range(len(labels_arr)):   # needed first to loop through the list of lists
    nums_arr_i=[]                  # this array needed to append the 1's and 0's to it
    for key in Dict.keys():        # after we loop through the Dict keys first
        if key in labels_arr[i]:   # compares the keys to original labels array at [i]
            nums_arr_i.append(1)   # append 1 or 0 if it matches or not
        else:
            nums_arr_i.append(0)
    nums_arr.append(nums_arr_i)    # end result list of 7 1's or 0's is appended to 
print('nums_arr= ', nums_arr)      # nums_arr and we loop to the next i in labels_arr

# End Result
nums_arr=  [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should build your dictionary the other way around (i.e. keys should be the labels).  This would allow you to convert the labels into indexes.
To obtain your final list of 1s and 0s, you don't need to go through an intermediate step with a list of indexes, you can build that list directly from the source data:

```
Dict = {'label1':1,
        'label2':2,
        'label3':3,
        'label4':4,
        'label5':5,
        'label6':6,
        'label7':7}


lines1 = """label1
label4
label3""".split("\n")

lines2 = """label3
label1""".split("\n")

lbl = [lines1,lines2] # <-- this is a list of lists (of strings) like yours

result = [0]+[0]*max(Dict.values())
for lineList in lbl:
    for line in lineList:
        result[Dict.get(line,0)] = 1 # <-- notice how this is using line, not lbl
result = result[1:]

print(result)
# [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I can see that, as your code is, it works beautifully.  However,when I put it in my code, I get this error and it doesn't make
 sense. 
    result[Dict.get(lbl, 0)] = 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Expected type 'str' (matched generic type '_KT'), got 'List[str]' instead

Comment: I suspect your lbl variable is not a string but a list of strings.

Comment: Shouldn't yours be as well?  
`
lbl = {list: 3} ['label1', 'label5', 'label4']
 0 = {str} 'label1'
 1 = {str} 'label5'
 2 = {str} 'label4'
 __len__ = {int} 3`

Comment: `lbl = {list: 3} ['label1', 'label5', 'label4']` tells me that lbl is a list of strings.  In my example, i am going through each item of my list of strings (called lines) in a for loop, so my label variable is a string.

Comment: My list (lines) looks like this               [['lable1', 'lable5', 'lable4'], ['lable1', 'lable4', 'lable3'], ['lable1', 'lable3'], ['lable1'], ['lable1', 'lable4', 'lable3'],.......]
Isn't this a list of string, like yours, but if I implement the same as you suggest, shouldn't it lop through like your example?  I guess I am unsure how to change it to make it loop through the same.  do I need 2 for loops?

Comment: Yes you will need two loops because you actually have a list of lists and you want to go through all items of the nested lists.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know I am not that good at loops.
y = [['lable1', 'lable5', 'lable4'], ['lable1', 'lable4', 'lable3'], ['lable1', 'lable3']]
result = [0]+[0]*max(Dict.values())
for j in (lbl[1] for lbl in y):
    result[Dict.get(lbl, 0)] = 1
result = result[1:]

Comment: It doesn't like lbl in  the line result[Dict.get(lbl,0)]=1.
Says it is an unhashable type: 'list'.  I see https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension that  lists are not hashable.  I guess I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I'll adjust the example to show how to process a list of lists...

Comment: Definitely helpful, thank you .  Would you mind explaining what the 1 in this line means/does?      
result[Dict.get(line,0)] = 1

Comment: `result` starts out with all zeroes.  The  `Dict` keyed on labels returns an index in `result` when accessed using the `line`.  So we are assigning the '1' that you want in your final result to positions of the `result`list using this indirection.   Dict.get(line,0) is equivalent to Dict[line] but will return a zero if line is not one of the labels in Dict.  Position zreo of the result array is like a trash can for all theses non-matching labels.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Alain T. that it's better to reverse the Dict. However in case you want to keep it as it is:

```
Dict = {1:'label1',2:'label2',3:'label3',4:'label4',5:'label5',6:'label6',7:'label7'}

lables_arr=['label1','label4','label3']        

nums_arr=[]
for x,y in Dict.items():
    for z in lables_arr:
        if z==y:
            nums_arr.append(x)

nums_arr.sort()

final=[]
for i in range(len(Dict)):
    if i not in nums_arr:
        final.append(0)
    else:
        final.append(1)

print(final)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```